# How to take data from rows and put it into single field?

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by

I have the following database:

```
paperid  | authorid |       name       |                                   affiliation                                   
---------+----------+------------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  487792 |  1487835 | Mark A. Magnuson | Vanderbilt University
  487792 |  1814994 | Miriam Magnuson  | Department of Education and Psychology, Linköping University, Linköping, Sweden
  487792 |  2248713 | Leif Hergils     | Department of Audiology, University Hospital, Linköping, Sweden
```

I would like to make something like this out of it:

```
paperid  |                 name                                    |
---------+---------------------------------------------------------+
  487792 | Mark A. Magnuson Miriam Magnuson Leif Hergils
```

By putting all author's names in one column/field.

How can I do this with SQL?

**EDIT**

I have tried :

```
select paperid, concat(name) as authors FROM newpaperauthor GROUP BY paperid, name ORDER BY paperid;
```

But this will list the authors separately:

```
 paperid |          authors           
---------+----------------------------
  896450 | Bart Dhoedt
  896450 | Marc De Leenheer
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
select paperid, string_agg(name, ' ') as authors 
FROM newpaperauthor 
GROUP BY paperid 
ORDER BY paperid;
```

`string_agg` does string concatenation by aggregating a column:

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-aggregate.html#FUNCTIONS-AGGREGATE-TABLE

`concat` does string concatenation of the supplied parameters:

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-OTHER

Comment: Can you explain the difference between `string_agg(name, ' ')` and `concat(name)`?

Answer (score 0):

`concat(x,y)` glues together two scalar values (e.g. two column values in the same row). string_agg(name, sep) glues together the values of column `name` within one aggregation group. Since there is no guarantee of ordering within that group, caveat emptor; and check out SQL-2003-level aggregations like `PARTITION` where you can specify orders.